# pushRef.set() is not a function, Firebase query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

This is my code:

```
var pushRef = currentAssignment.child('answers').push().catch(e => console.log('push', e));
pushRef.set({
    // downloadURL: downURL,
    textAnswer: textAnswer,
    date: this.generateDate(),
    seen: false,
    // firebaseKey: pushRef.getKey(),
    workKey: this.props.questionId
})
```

When I try to run it, I get this error: `pushRef.set()`, but according to [this part of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) it looks to me like I'm doing everything the same way. Here's Google's example of push instruction:

```
var postsRef = ref.child("posts");
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
newPostRef
    .set({
        author: "gracehop",
        title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    });

// we can also chain the two calls together
postsRef
    .push()
    .set({
        author: "alanisawesome",
        title: "The Turing Machine"
    });
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: What is that `.catch()` doing behind `push()`?

Comment: In case of an error, it will console.log it

Comment: Did you try it without that? As far as I know push won't ever generate an error....

Comment: @AndréKool you're right. Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `.catch(e => console.log('push', e))` behind `push()` you change it from a firebase database reference to something else. So removing that will fix this.

As far as I know calling `push()` (without parameters) will never generate an error, it simply generates a firebase reference (unique key) client side.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is expecting that `catch()` returns a database reference.  It doesn't - `catch()` always returns a promise.

The use of catch here is unnecessary because [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference#push) with no arguments is a completely local operation.  It returns a database reference that can also be used like a promise (a [ThenableReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference)).

If there is any error to possibly catch here, it's on the promise returned by [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference#set).  That call will fail if security rules are violated during the write operation.